# How to reread data each certain amount of time on shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I am creating a program in Shiny and I have the following problem: my data files are getting changed automatically each minute and I want to display information like plots from that data files. How can I make the application to automatically reread the data frames each minute? The problem I have is that I have to use a function created by me to read the data so I don't read them with functions like `read.table` or `read.csv`.

I'll try to provide an example of the code I have:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardBody(
selectInput("estprediction" , label = "Est" , choices = c("A1" , "A2" , "A3"  , "A4" , "A5" , "A6" , "A7"),selectize = TRUE)),
plotOutput(outputId = "predictionplot"))
)
server <- function(input, output) {
data1 <- readweirddata("A1")
data2 <- readweirddata("A2")
...
data7 <- readweirddata("A7")
  fecha_min <- as.POSIXct(mutate(data1,Date = paste(Year, Month, Day, Hour, Min, sep = "-"))$Date,format = "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M") 

estpred <- reactiveValues(data=data1)
observeEvent(input$estprediction, {
    if (input$estprediction== "A1"){estpred$data = data1}
    if (input$estprediction== "A2"){estpred$data = data2}
    if (input$estprediction== "A3"){estpred$data = data3}
    if (input$estprediction== "A4"){estpred$data = data4}
    if (input$estprediction== "A5"){estpred$data = data5}
    if (input$estprediction== "A6"){estpred$data = data6}
    if (input$estprediction== "A7"){estpred$data = data7}
  })

 output$predictionplot <- renderPlot({
    df <- data.frame(fecha_min,estpred$data[c(1,2,4)])
    ggplot(df, aes(fecha_min)) + 
    geom_line(size=1,aes(y = estpred$data[1], colour = paste("Var1", "min(μg/m3)")))} +
geom_line(size=1,aes(y = estpred$data[2], colour = paste("Var1", "min(μg/m3)")))} +
geom_line(size=1,aes(y = estpred$data[4], colour = paste("Var1", "min(μg/m3)")))} 

  })

}
```

When someone runs the program it will read the present data, but as each minute those data frames are going to change but shinny app is not going to reread them again. How could I make the app to each minute reread  the data files when I have to use the `readweirddata` function?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: see `?reactiveFileReader`

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, I already did, but I don't know how can I use it in my example. What I mean is: should I use ```reactiveFileReader(1000,NULL,readweirddata("A1"),NULL)```? Or how do I do it? I got the problem because I have to use this function ```readweirddata <- function(termination){...}```to read data files.